# NodeJS [Passport] Reset password

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm currently trying to add a Strategy in order to change the user password, but I don't really understand how I have to manipulate Passport.
My goal is to take 3 arguments:

- Current password
- New password
- New password confirmation

But it seems that we're limited to usernameField and passwordField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passport doesn’t give you a way to do this, it’s only concerned with authentication.  You’re left to figure this out on your own.

If you search the web you’ll find that most people are implementing a simple route handler that accepts a form submission and modifies the password in the user database.  This works but it ignores a lot of security issues, like implementing password strength rules or properly authenticating the user (for example, by sending a password reset link/token to their email address).

Disclaimer: I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and we <3 password reset (and authentication!).  We have very secure workflows for password management.  If you’re using Express I recommend our article on this topic:

https://stormpath.com/blog/the-pain-of-password-reset/